# How to fix Hibernate using annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate

During testing `CRUD` I have used `createQuery()` method to generate the `HQL` query to return data from `MySQL` DB.
My code have been underline with error message:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Student'  This inspection controls whether the
>   Persistence QL Queries are error-checked

In my opinion there is some problem with `@Entity` annotation in the database model class.

Student.java

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Student() {

    }
```

QueryStudentDemo.java

```java
    public class QueryStudentDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                                    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                    .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                                    .buildSessionFactory();

        //create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try{

            //use the session object to save Java object


            //begin the transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            //query students
            List<Student> studentList = session.createQuery("from Student").getResultList();


            //display the students
            for (Student student: studentList){
                System.out.println("Student: " + student);
            }

            //commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            System.out.println("Transaction done!");


        }finally {
            factory.close();
        }
```

```xml
hibernate.cfg.xml

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hbstudent</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hbstudent</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: On which line does it say `Cannot resolve symbol 'Student' This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are error-checked`? And btw unrelated but I noticed that your connection pool size is set to 1, wondering why is that?

Comment: can you try removing `@Table` annotation and its value?

Comment: Connection pool size I have took from the template thst size is enaugh in that kind project which I test just for mysekf. Error appears at: 
            List<Student> studentList = session.createQuery("from Student").getResultList();

Comment: Deleting @Table didnt help, It still inform me that Student is not mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `hibernate.cfg.xml` missing `<mapping class="your classname" />`

-first of all change your table name in student class replace @Table(name="student") to @Table(name="Student")

- Second use Session session = factory.openSession(); this instead of    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
- List studentList = session.createQuery("from Student").getResultList(); replace this with

Query query = session.createQuery(s);
List studentList = query.list();
after that you can run

Comment: But I would like to creat mapping using annotation @Entity without declaring that in hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Comment: Is it posiible to generate mapping without doing that in the hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: without mapping, it is not possible, you need to a mapping of your class in your hibernate.cfg.xml file

Comment: I execute your code after some changes it is working

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Entity class and config is ok, except for session creation.
 Replace your this code:

```
//create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                                    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                    .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                                    .buildSessionFactory();

        //create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
```

With this one:

```
Configuration conf= new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Student.class); 

ServiceRegistry reg= new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

SessionFactory sf= conf.buildSessionFactory(reg); 
Session session= sf.openSession();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It isn't that kind of problem. Sory. And thank you for attention.